# Reading .csv file into C LinkedList

Tags: c, parsing, data-structures, linked-list, nodes

I have the following `struct`:

```
struct NODE {
    char username[50];
    char password[50];
    char usertype[50];
    struct NODE *next;
} *head=NULL;
```

I would like to read from a `.csv` file, say `database.csv` of the form `username, password, usertype`, tokenize each line into tokens using `strtok` and put each token inside the right field. For instance, my file looks like this:

`johnnydepp, pirate123, user`
`tonystark, iron456, sysop`

I keep reading on C `LinkedList`, but I cannot figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciate, or any good references on how to implement a `LinkedList` in C.

My main problem is putting element in the each of the node. I know how to use `strtok` to tokenize a line in a file. This is what I have done so far:

```
void createList() {
    FILE *data;
    data = fileopen("password.csv", "r");
    char parsedLine[50];
    while (fgets(parsedLine, 50, data) != NULL) {
    char *ptr = strtok(parsedLine, ", ");
        node *temp;
        temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    // I am stuck here //
}
```

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Will this work?

```
extern void createList() {

FILE *data;
data = fileopen("password.csv", "r");
char parsedLine[50];
while (fgets(parsedLine, 50, data) != NULL) {
    struct NODE *node = malloc(sizeof(struct NODE));
    char *getUser = strtok(parsedLine, ", ");
    strcpy(node->username, getUser);
    char *getPass = strtok(NULL, ", "); 
    strcpy(node->password, getPass);
    char *getType = strtok(NULL, ", ");
    strcpy(node->usertype, getType);    
    node->next = head;
    head = node;
}
fclose(data);

}
```

Comment: What is it you have trouble with? The linked list? Reading/parsing the CSV file? Can you be more specific, and if possible show us the code you tried (but please read http://sscce.org/ before posting all your code).

Comment: You'll need to allocate the new node once in the loop; then you'll need to call `strtok()` three times (and `strcpy()` too) to split the input line and copy the values found into the new node. When you're sure the data is valid, you hook the new node into the list as in Joachim's answer. If there's a problem, you must decide what to do about it — abandon ship, release the new node and try again with the next line, or ... I'm not a big fan of `strtok()` for a number of reasons. It works OK in limited contexts like this, but you must be very careful with it. Don't use it in a library function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's actually very simple... You have a `NODE` structure, which contains a `next` pointer, and a variable `head` which points to the head (first node) of the list. The head pointer starts out as `NULL` meaning the list is empty.

To add a node you create a node, then set the newly created nodes `next` pointer to point to the current head of the list, and set the head to point to the new node:

```
/* Allocate new node */
struct NODE *node = malloc(sizeof(struct NODE));

/* Link to the current head */
node->next = head;

/* Make the new node the head of the list */
head = node;
```

After doing this once, you have a list containing one node. After doing it twice you have a two-node list. Etc.

Comment: Now that I have this clear in my head, may I ask if my synthax for `strtok` is correct? How do I store the content of my `.csv` file inside the field of a node? Perhaps I should make a `add(struct NODE *p)` function to loop through my file and keep adding nodes to my list?

Comment: @iHubble I recommend putting all list-handling in separate functions. The `strtok` call is good to get the first sub-string, use a loop with `strtok(NULL, ", ")` to get the remaining values. After you have done the `strtok` use `strcpy` to copy to the correct fields: `strcpy(node->username, ptr);` etc.

Comment: I need to use an `add` method to add any node to my `LinkedList`. Such function uses a pointer to a node, as I wrote above. How could I read from my `.csv` file and use this `add` function at the same time?